# Copying custom string in C using pointers to uint64_t causes segmentation fault

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault, copying

As the title says, whenever I try to copy string (using my own string type and library) I get a segmentation fault. According to debugger it happens at 29th line of source (where s_strcpy4() is called), which goes to the line in sstring.h with "_dest[i] = _sour[i];". *i* seems to have some different value from time to time at the time of the crash, but some times sticks to one value (not sure why yet). As of the writing it got stuck at 16896.

Anyone knows where I could be causing the segfault in the code?

source.c

```
#include "sstring.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    s_string ss1,
                     ss2;
    long long int start, end;
    struct timespec time;
    FILE *LoremIpsum;

    s_init(&ss1, NULL, 65536);
    s_init(&ss2, NULL, 65536);

    LoremIpsum = fopen("Lorem ipsum", "r");
    if(LoremIpsum == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening file ");
        return 1;
    }

    fgets(ss2.string, 65536, LoremIpsum);

    if(fclose(LoremIpsum) == EOF) {
        perror("Error closing file ");
        return 2;
    }

    s_strcpy4(&ss1, &ss2);

    return 0;
}
```

sstring.h

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

    enter code here

typedef struct {
    int length;
    char *string;
} s_string;

s_string *s_init(s_string *str, char *array, size_t num) {
    int i;

    if(str == NULL) 
        str = malloc(sizeof(s_string));

    if(array == NULL) {
        (*str).length = num;

        if(num != 0)
            (*str).string = malloc(num);
    } else {
        if(num == 0) {
            (*str).string = NULL;

            for(i = 0; array[i] != '\0'; i++) {
                (*str).string = realloc((void *)(*str).string, i + 1);
                (*str).string[i] = array[i];
            }

            (*str).length = i;
        } else {
            (*str).string = (char *)malloc(num);

            (*str).length = num;

            for(i = 0; i < num; i++)
                (*str).string[i] = array[i];
        }
    }

    return str;
}

s_string *s_strcpy4(s_string *__restrict__ destination, const s_string *__restrict__ source) {
    int i;
    long long  *_dest = (long long *)(destination->string),
                         *_sour = (long long *)(source->string);

    for(i = 0; i < source->length - 8; i+=8)
        _dest[i] = _sour[i];

    for( ; i < source->length; i++)
        destination->string[i] = source->string[i];

    destination->length = i;

    return destination;
}
```

Comment: `s_init(p, NULL, 0)` doesn't initialize `p->string`. I'm not sure it's *the* problem, but it's *a* problem.

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize that. Now it sets p->string to NULL in that case.

Answer (score 1):

_dest[i] = _sour[i];
 should be
  _dest[i/8] = _sour[i/8];

or something equivalent.

There are lots of other things wrong with the code. For example, on architectures that require properly aligned pointers, trying to access a group of eight characters that don't start on a multiple-of-eight address will cause a bus error.

I assume you are doing this as an exercise, and not to use in production. Just use memcpy()

Comment: Would be nice to know _what_ is wrong with my code and not just that there are a lot of things wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
size_t const LLsize = sizeof(long long);
for(i = 0; i < source->length / LLsize; ++i)
    _dest[i] = _sour[i];

for( i = i*LLsize; i < source->length; ++i)
    destination->string[i] = source->string[i];
```